# Piping command with seemingly several separate outputs to file

Tags: python, subprocess

I am using [speedtest-cli](https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli) to get my internet speed in a python script. I would like to run this command in shell via `subprocess.Popen`.

Here is the command in terminal:

```
`speedtest-cli --share > output.log`
```

`speedtest-cli` runs the test, whilst `--share` provides me with an additional link in the output, pointing to an image of the speedtest result. Here is the content of `output.log`:

> Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
>   Testing from M-net (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)...
>   Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
>   Selecting best server based on ping...
>   Hosted by XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX [16.12 km]: 20.902 ms
>   Testing download speed................................................................................
>   Download: 48.32 Mbit/s
>   Testing upload speed......................................................................................................
>   Upload: 12.49 Mbit/s
>   Share results: http://www.speedtest.net/result/670483456.png

If I run the command in terminal, I get all the test results as well as the link in the target file as expected. I confirmed it is all `stdout` and not another channel by using this [grep trick](https://superuser.com/questions/453598/determine-if-output-is-stdout-or-stderr#comment529379_453604): `command | grep .`

I am trying to run it in Python as follows:

```
subprocess.Popen(['speedtest-cli', '--share', '>', 'output.log`],
                  stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

...and I also tried putting the output into the file directly via python:

```
with open('output.log', 'w') as f:
    Popen(['speedtest-cli', '--json', '--share'], stdout=f, shell=True)
```

Neither of these work. I get a nice file created with the latter approach, BUT the link is not included! (the last line in the output above).

Against all the warnings of deprecation and better safety with using `subprocess` module, I became desparate and tried `os.system()`:

```
os.system('speedtest-cli --share > output.log')
```

Annoyingly, this works... the full output along with the link is captured in the file.

**What is going on here? How do I get the link to be captured using `Popen`?**

I'm using Python 3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `shell=True`, your argument to `Popen` needs to be a *string*, not a list:

```
subprocess.Popen('speedtest-cli --json --share > output.log',
                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

Compare:

```
>>> subprocess.Popen('echo hello', shell=True)
>>> hello
```

And:

```
>>> subprocess.Popen(['echo', 'hello'], shell=True)
>>>
```

When you pass a list and you are using `shell=True`, only the the first item is relevant and the remainder is ignored.

If you want to collect the output yourself, consider `subprocess.check_output`:

```
>>> output = subprocess.check_output(['echo', 'hello'])
>>> output
b'hello\n'
```

Or:

```
>>> output = subprocess.check_output('echo hello', shell=True)
```

The `check_output` method works with both Python 2 and Python 3.  In Python 3, you also have available the [run](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) method.

Comment: Thank you - I simply needed to create a single string. In your first code example, you have the single string as a list, which doesn"t work then - should it be corrected?

Comment: Actually, that works fine ("...only the the first item is relevant and the remainder is ignored..."), but it was a typo and I have fixed it.

Comment: shell=True is a security nightmare.  So it's best practise to use shell=False and pass a list of parameters.  (It's not a security problem in this case, as it's only exploitable if an attacker can control one of the parameters.  But it's still best to avoid it).

Comment: @user9876 - I was waiting for someone to leave that customary comment when `shell=True` pops up  ;)